# Cannot read property 'id' of undefined on ngOnInit() Angular7

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular7

I am beginner to angular. Problem is actually in EmployeeComponent.ts , if i call  `this.resetForm();` in `ngOnInit()` then the controls of dialog gets displayed during page load... but during edit when it comes from employeelist the `service.formData` sets back to null all time i don't want this to happen. I want both functionalities to happen.

This below error if i `remove this.resetForm();` in `ngOnInit()`. (but edit works fine)   Note : `service.formData` contains fields id, description and active

> Consolelog error : EmployeeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at EmployeeComponent.push.

EmployeeComponent.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.resetForm();
}


resetForm(form ? : NgForm) {

  if (form != null)
    form.resetForm();

  this.service.formData = {
    id: null,
    description: '',
    active: true,
  }
  console.log(this.service.formData.id);
}
```

EmployeeListComponent.ts

```
onEdit(emp: Employee) {
  this.service.formData = Object.assign({}, emp);
  const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
  dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
  dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
  dialogConfig.width = "50%";
  this.dialog.open(EmployeeComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

Employee.component.html

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off" >
  <mat-grid-list cols="2">
          <input type="hidden" name="id" #id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.id">       
        <mat-form-field>   
          <input name="description" matInput #description="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.description" placeholder="Employee" required>  
   </mat-form-field>
 <mat-checkbox  matInput #active="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="service.formData.active" name="active">Active</mat-checkbox>         
  </mat-grid-list>
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid" (click)="onSubmit(form)">Submit</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="warn" style="margin-left: 6px;" (click)="onClear(form)">Clear</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here EmployeeComponent is your mat dialog component to open so you need to provide data to the dialog using below in your constructor of EmployeeComponent

```
 constructor(
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data)){}
```

and when you open the dialog for editing purpose, you need to set data

```
  onEdit(emp: Employee) {
      dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
      dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
      dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
      dialogConfig.width = "50%";
      // Provide your data here      
      dialogConfig.data = emp;

      this.dialog.open(EmployeeComponent, dialogConfig);
    }
```

Now you can use this data on EmployeeComponent by name "data" property

and only use reset form in ngOninit

```
ngOnInit() {
if (form != null)
    form.resetForm();
}
```

Other things you need to handle like clear this data when you have done with save

Comment: constructor(
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data)){} . How to do it. It gives me error in EmployeeComponent.ts

Comment: cant i use with service.formData?

Comment: you can refer this link to get better understanding https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-dialog/ to resolve the error you need to import like this import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material"; you should use  data to inject please don't use service because it will conflict your logic with reset form when open the dialog